# jQueryRangeSlider With Quarters and Months Displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

All,
I am using jQRangeSlider (http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/) to fulfill a requirement that I have. I am trying to get a Date Range Selector that,

1. Shows the current Fiscal Year at the top.
2. Shows Quarters in the middle (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4).
3. Shows months at the bottom.

Please see image provided below.

[image: End Result / product- date ranges]

I can get the months to render properly, but I cannot seem to figure out how I would also show the Quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4) and the FY17 heading.

This might not even be possible with the current plugin that I am using, so if someone has another suggestion, I am all ears.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var today = new Date();
var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
var todayMonth = today.getMonth();
var todayDay = today.getDate();

var nextYear = todayYear + 1;
var nextMonth = todayMonth +1;
var nextDay = 1;

var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: {min: new Date(todayYear, 09, 01), max: new Date(nextYear, 08, 30)},
    defaultValues: {min: new Date(todayYear, todayMonth, todayDay), max: new Date(nextYear, nextMonth, nextDay)},
    scales: [{
      first: function(value){ 
        return value; 
        },
      end: function(value) {
        return value; 
        },
      next: function(value){
        var next = new Date(value);
        return new Date(next.setMonth(value.getMonth() + 1));
      },
      label: function(value){
        return months[value.getMonth()];
      },
      format: function(tickContainer, tickStart, tickEnd){
        tickContainer.addClass("myCustomClass");
      }
    }]
});
```

I understand that I should use a secondary scale, but I am not sure how I can implement that from a Quarter perspective.

Here is my jsFiddle, forked from another example: http://jsfiddle.net/zegr37d9/1/

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this post. We ended up deciding to not go through with the whole requirement (FY / Quarter / Month) which is described above. But I believe that this can be accomplished by sliding in a couple of divs within the #slider element.